# Convert JSON string into Date time and compare swift

Tags: json, swift, datetime, nsdateformatter

I Have two question :
1) I want to convert the JSON string into time . I am getting the JSON String but i am not able to convert it into Time.
Following is my code :

`HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON ["status": 200, "data": 15:55, "Message": In Time]`

the "data" i am getting is in string want to convert the data into actual time

```
if let datetime = json["data"] as? String {
    print("on CLick of in_time BUtton : \(datetime)")
    let formattter = DateFormatter()
    formattter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    formattter.date(from: datetime)
    print("form : \(formattter)")
    print("Date : \(datetime)")
}
```

2) I Have a Grace time and I want to Compare it with the server time which i will get through json How i can Achieve it Please help !!!
grace time is 10:30

Comment: Why are you using a full date format when your JSON clearly only contains the time with minutes precision? Simply set `dateFormat` to `HH:mm`.

Comment: Even after using that i am getting error when i print "form" `form : <NSDateFormatter: 0x604000255000>`

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see by printing `formatter`?

Comment: and how i can compare the time with the grace time if it is before grace time or after grace time. because in Android i am using it as `datetime.before(gracetime)` what i can use here ?

Comment: @SandeshZote what error are you getting? You can simply compare `Date` objects using the comparison operators, namely `datetime < gracetime`. You also should print `formatter`, that makes no sense, you should print `formatter.date(from: datetime)`.

Comment: in `formatter` i will get the formatted time ??

Comment: Also, have in mind that if you have set 12-hour format in your device's settings, you need to set the locale for your `formatter`

Comment: the updated time i will get as `let time = formatter.date(from: datetime)`

Comment: @mag_zbc can you explain me more ?? any device can have 12 hour format how i can use locale ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use like:**

```
 if let strResp = json["data"]{
        let strDate = "\(strResp!)" //15:55
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // Pass any format here you want according to your date response
        let convDate = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
        print(convDate!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `formattter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` to `formattter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"` as @Dávid Pásztor said

Comment: He should also set the locale to `formattter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: `let time = formattter.date(from: datetime)
                            print("form : \(String(describing: time))")` and getting the value as `form : Optional(2000-01-01 11:04:00 +0000)`

Comment: you need to unwrap the optional result using `if let` instead of `let`. You need also to use date formatter to convert your date back to string. `formatter.string(from: time)`

Comment: @LeoDabus i am sorry i did not undestand

Comment: if you print a date you will get UTC time representation. If you would like to see the local time you need to use date formatter. `if let time = formattter.date(from: datetime) {` and when printing `print(formatter.string(from: time))`

Comment: don't forget to set the date formatter locale to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: Ok I got it ?? now i have to use this `time` and compare it with `grace time`

Comment: is `grace time` a string or Date type?

Comment: `gracetime` is a string

Comment: convert it to date format as the time you got from JSON and then you can look here how to compare two dates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018335/swift-3-comparing-date-objects

Comment: can i directly fetch the data as `let datetime = json["data"] as? Date`

Comment: No, because json["data"] is a string type!

Comment: can i send the data as date format only through backend itself ?? will it be possible and then fetch it as Date then i wont have to convert it to date format and then again string

Comment: Normally time is returned as string in API responses and everyone here told you how to access it, so why are you insisting with this idea of date type?

Comment: yes i do agree with everyone . i just got a thought . i am not implementing that . but wanted to know if we can do it as well . Thank you for helping @DionizB