# Filter array of objects if property value exists in another array of objects swift

Tags: arrays, swift, object, filter

I have two array of objects that look like this:

`MeetingRoomSuggestions`:

```
init(suggestionReason: String, organizerAvailability: String,
startTime: String, endTime: String, dStart: Date, availability: String,
emailAddress: String, displayName: String, roomEmail: String,
occupancy: Int, building: String)
```

and `Bookings`:

```
init(startTime: String, endTime: String, dStart: Date, organizer :
String, location : String, subject : String)
```

I want to be able to filter / exclude `MeetingRoomSuggestion` objects from my array if the `dStart` property exists in the `Bookings` array.

My Code:

```
  let filteredArr = meetingRoomSuggestions.filter { meeting in
        return bookingArray!.contains(where: { booking in
            return booking.dStart == meeting.dStart
        })
    }
```

I also tried filtering on the start string - which is the same in both.
When I print out both the arrays before filtering - you can clearly see there is a booking that exists with the same `dStart`. How can I exclude this?

After filtering and printing out using the code:

```
print("meetings:")
        for meeting in self.meetingRoomSuggestions {
            print(meeting.roomEmail)
            print(meeting.dStart)
            print(meeting.startTime)
        }
        print()
        print("bookings:")
        for booking in self.bookingArray! {
            print(booking.location)
            print(booking.dStart!)
            print(booking.start)
        }            

        print("filtered array: ", filteredArr)

        for items in filteredArr {
            print("email: ", items.roomEmail)
            print("dstart: ", items.dStart)
        }
```

Returns:

```
    meetings:
FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
2019-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
2019-02-20T15:00:00.0000000
GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
2019-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
2019-02-20T15:00:00.0000000

bookings:
FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
2019-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
2019-02-20T15:00:00.0000000
gfprojectroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
2019-02-21 10:00:00 +0000
2019-02-21T10:00:00.0000000
gfprojectroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
2019-02-21 16:00:00 +0000
2019-02-21T16:00:00.0000000

filtered array:  [QUBook.MeetingSuggestion, QUBook.MeetingSuggestion]
email:  FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
dstart:  2019-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
email:  GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com
dstart:  2019-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
```

For some reason, the filtered array is the same as the original `meetingRoomSuggestions` array - it doesn't filter out the occurrence of an object with the same `dStart`. I suspect the filter is wrong? I have previously been able to filter array of objects by comparing them with array of strings etc but not like this.

Comment: In MeetingRoomSuggestions init where are you initializing dstart ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using some kind of reverse logic here. What you should be doing is this:

```
let filteredArr = meetingRoomSuggestions.filter { meeting in
    return !bookingArray.contains(where: { booking in
        return booking.dStart == meeting.dStart
    })
}
```

In plain english: `filter` meetings, leaving those that `do not` have their `dStart` values equal to the `dStart` value of any object in the `bookingArray`.

Comment: edited my answer. I tried this way of filtering firstly and it wouldn't filter out the meeting I wanted.. Does not pick up / filter even though there is a booking with the same dStart? ^ See prints above

Comment: @Liam, I think you forgot the `!`, as in `!bookingArray.contains`

Comment: @LeoDabus, well, I do not think so. At least not when explaining something to someone.

Comment: @LeoDabus, no, I would not. This is not a place where it would be elegant, which kinda defeats the only purpose implicit returns have.

Comment: how would I alter this filter statement to filter out any meeting suggestions that have a start time that is before the ending of any other booking? e.g. booking.dStart == meeting.dStart or booking.dStart + booking.duration >=  meeting.dStart?

Comment: @Liam, yep, something like that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018335/swift-3-comparing-date-objects

Comment: can you look at my edit please - would I have to change the filter to this to resolve?                 return (booking.dStart == meeting.dStart) && (booking.roomEmail == meeting.roomEmail)

Comment: @Liam, sure, feel free to adjust the filter logic according to your requirements