# How to compare 2 date without compare microsecond?

Tags: swift5, swift-playground

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018335/swift-3-comparing-date-objects). But when i run this bellow code in playground, have a bit chance it will be print "false".
I think the reason is microsecond when initialize Date object.

Have any better way? Or how to compare without microsecond?

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()
print(date1)
print(date2)

print(date1 == date2)
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to print in millisecond, but i saw they same.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calender` provides a convenient API to do that

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()

let isInSameSecond = Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .second) == .orderedSame
```

Change `toGranularity` to the desired level.

Comment: It's work, thank you. May you give me a way to show Date in nanosecond?